# How do I get rid of old linux-headers-3.xx.x-xx files?

Tags: kernel, 15.04, disk-usage

I frequently run into the problem that I don't have enough space on `/boot` left. When that happens, I use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/259092/225200) to free space.

The output of the command shown there gives me not only a bunch of old (and current) images, but also a lot more `headers` files. It does not list the current kernel.

```
foo:~/Desktop $ dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]'
linux-headers-3.16.0-38
linux-headers-3.16.0-39
linux-headers-3.16.0-39-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-21
linux-headers-3.19.0-21-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-22
linux-headers-3.19.0-22-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-23
linux-headers-3.19.0-23-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-25
linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-26
linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic
linux-image-3.19.0-23-generic
linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic
```

I usually remove all but the current kernel and the previous one. However, those `headers` are way older. Some are 3.16 while I am now on 3.19.

Do I need those, or can I get rid of them?

How do I remove them?

Comment: have a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt --purge remove linux-headers-3.19.0-23 linux-headers-3.19.0-23-generic ...
```

This removes the named packages which contain said header files.

Comment: Can you please explain what this command does?